# If statement in val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two fields and one checkbox.

I need to send data from first field to second through the val().

But if checkbox is checked I need to add some text, if checkbox in unchecked I need to add some text too.

For example if checked add "checked", unchecked - "unchecked".

This is the sample of code

```
var length = $('#fieldname7_3_caption').html();
var width = $('#fieldname8_3_caption').html();
$('.field-hidden').val('First var:' + firstVar+ '\nSecond var: ' + secondVar + if($('#fieldname28_3').is(':checked')) ? 'checked' : 'unckecked');
```

But in console I get this error:

### Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @RobbyCornelissen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a single line *ternary if statement* and therefore you should remove the `if`..

Like so:

```
var length = $('#fieldname7_3_caption').html();
var width = $('#fieldname8_3_caption').html();
$('.field-hidden').val('First var:' + firstVar+ '\nSecond var: ' + secondVar + $('#fieldname28_3').is(':checked') ? 'checked' : 'unckecked');
```

Read more on ternary here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Thanks! When i removed "if" - it was earned!

Answer (score 4):

Lose the `if` :

```
var length = $('#fieldname7_3_caption').html();
var width = $('#fieldname8_3_caption').html();
$('.field-hidden').val('First var:' + firstVar+ '\nSecond var: ' + secondVar + ($('#fieldname28_3').is(':checked')) ? 'checked' : 'unckecked');
```

or Simplify it:

```
var length = $('#fieldname7_3_caption').html();
var width = $('#fieldname8_3_caption').html();

var res1 = 'First var:' + firstVar + '\nSecond var: ' + secondVar; 

var res2 = if($('#fieldname28_3').is(':checked')) ? 'checked' : 'unckecked';

var res = res1 + res2;

$('.field-hidden').val(res);
```

Comment: Though its correct, please add explanation as you are answering for readers

Comment: Thanks, @JamesPage!